# How to make the thumb slider smooth

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I have created a `thumb slider`, but it is not working smoothly [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rohankumar/ebszR/embedded/result/).

It works, but when I click on `prev` then it not look like smooth, because I am using `prepend after animate function`. Same, for `next`
How can I solve this problem, and make it smooth.

**Also,** I want to convert it into `jquery plugin` then how I can convert it.

Any suggestion or help?

Thanks.

Comment: Maybe prepend the slide before or during animation? http://learn.jquery.com/plugins/ (about jQuery plugins)

Comment: Try to prepend/append before animate:)

Comment: How have you tried to solve your problem? Looks like your logic is failing. BTW, there is already hundred of jquery's plugin which seems to do what you are looking for, why not strating to see how they do it?

Comment: I have tried `prependTo` before `animate` but no results.

Comment: The css is still firing before the append,  please retrace your steps.  First add  then slide.

Comment: Have a look at http://api.jquery.com/animate/ what functions and options jQuery animate has. You could use 'step' to add your slide while animating for example.

Answer (score 0):

After making many changes I didn't get any progress in it,

So I found a new simple [jcarousellite](http://www.gmarwaha.com/jquery/jcarousellite/), which works fine for me.

Thanks everyone who gave their `precious time` to solve my problem.